# how to test universal links on local server?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am developing an app on Android and IOS and I would like it to support universal links.
I already have an apple-app-site-association file deployed on my PROD server (which is something like www.example.com), but I need to redeploy a new one with some restrictions inside (to NOT allow some paths).
Before redeploying it, I would like to test it on my test server. So I deployed it on the test server (which is www.example.test.local).

To test, I modified my IOS app by changing in Associated Domains the param applinks:*.example.com by applinks:*.example.test.local. Then I builded my app and tried to click on an url which is www.example.test.local/myPath?myQueryParam=toto (which is not a 'NOT allowed' one). But instead of opening the app, it opened the index of my test server (if I rollback everything and click on an url like www.example.com/myPath, it works perfectly but it is the old apple-app-site-association file).

So did I miss something? What do I have to change to make it work on my test server?

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party here, but most likely your `.local` server was running on HTTP. You need to use HTTPS, with a valid certificate that the iOS device recognises (try fetching the AASA file by just typing in the URL, including `https://` prefix, into Safari; if you get "This Connection Is Not Private", then your cert isn't good enough - stepping through warnings and forcing Safari to visit the site anyway *may* be enough to get the trust store updated and have the wider system accept your cert).

Unfortunately, like everything to do with app links on iOS and Android, it's a huge pain and exceptionally developer-hostile. There does not seem to be any kind of easier test option for local machine development - or at least, nothing that I can find documented.